# Angular component doesn't render html, shows html route

Tags: angular, components

I have created a new component for Angular but I can't see the html rendered. Instead of the html rendered I've got the route to the html.

These are my folder structure:

[image]

This is the component created by me called **server.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    template: './server.component.html'
})
export class ServerComponent {

}
```

This is the html of the component, **server.component.html**:

```
<p>Este es mi nuevo componente!!!</p>
```

In **app.component.html** is where I include the tag of my component :

```
<div>
    <input type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "message" />
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <hr>
    *<app-server></app-server>*
</div>
```

And this is my **app.module.ts** code where I import ServerComponent to use it later:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
   ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is the result that I get in my browser:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace `template` by `templateUrl` in your component definition, it should be

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the server.component.ts you have used template attribute which requires you to pass a template between the . You need to use templateUrl attribute if you want to pass the link to a template.